# Assembly - sub instruction in the end of loop

Tags: assembly, x86

I read a book about assembly, which have the next code.  The code comapre (lexcially) two arrays (int value), and return 1 if the first is bigger, 0 if it equal or -1 otherwise:

```
Comprator:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  mov esi, [ebp+8] ; first - A
  mov edi, [ebp+12] ;Second - B
  mov ecx, [ebp+16]
  comp esi,edi,ecx
  jl less
  je equal
  mov eax, 1
  jmp end
equal:
   mov eax,0
   jmp end
less:
   mov eax, -1
   jmp end
end:
   pop ebp
   ret

%macro comp 3
    mov ecx, %3
%%l:
    mov eax,[%1]
    mov ebx,[%2]
    cmp eax,ebx
    jne %%done
    add %1, 4
    add %2, 4
    loop %%l
    sub eax,eax
%%done:
%endmacro
```

I don't undestand why it needs the line: `sub eax,eax`. If we have two identical arrays, so in the last compare, we would get, for example, `cmp 3,3` - then we will exit from the loop, and for the line `je equal` - it will return true, and would jump to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to set the Z flag so the `je equal` after the macro will know that the two arrays were equal. The Z flag would be set or cleared by the `cmp eax, ebx`, and if it's clear at that point, control will transfer to `done` -- unfortunately, immediately after that it does a couple of `add`s, which will (probably) clear the Z flag again, so the `sub eax, eax` is needed to set it again for the conditional jumps after the macro.

The real question would be why you need the `mov eax, 0` at `equal:` -- and the answer is that you don't. Along with setting the Z flag, the `sub eax, eax` also sets eax to 0, which can/could be returned directly. Even if you did decide to re-load the 0 value for some reason, you probably want to use the `sub eax, eax` (or `xor eax, eax`) to do so (the code is a little smaller and at least on some processors, faster as well).

Edit: I should add that at least in my opinion, this is a fairly poor use of a macro. At the very least, there should be some comments to specify the macro's interface, which would probably have answered the question before it was asked.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the function is returned in the EAX register. The final `sub eax, eax` is setting the value of EAX to zero before returning when the arrays match exactly.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why we need that? If we are doing cmp eax,ebx, so we get eax=eax-ebx. But eax=ebx, and for that eax=0, also without this line.

Comment: It does set eax to 0, but that's more or less incidental. If you look at where the `comp` macro is used, immediately after it there are a couple of conditional jumps that depend on its setting the Z flag, and ignore the value that's in eax.

Comment: @AdamSh: `cmp eax, ebx` won't change the value in `eax` -- it only affects the flags.